# python TypeError: float argument required, not list

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

*Non-commercial, non-professional user, seeking advice for hobbyist project.*

I have two Pi's set up like this:
Pi 1 hosts a Pimoroni Enviro Phat and writes its readings to a database also on Pi 1

Pi 2 hosts a Pimoroni Scroll PhatHD. 
I'd like it to read data from the database on Pi 1, and display it on the Scroll Phat HD on Pi 2

I've established all the necessary Mysql connection requirements, they're all good.

How to I get the readings from the database on Pi1 to scroll on the Scroll PhatHD on Pi 2?

```
import signal
import time
import scrollphathd
from scrollphathd.fonts import font5x7
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
con = mysql.connector.connect(host='192.168.#.##',database='test',user='#####',password='#######')


cur = con.cursor() 
cur.execute('SELECT Yaxis FROM readings ORDER BY Added DESC LIMIT 1')


### Keep trailing comma from SELECT result away: 
result = [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]

### Show result of SELECT query in terminal
print result

# temperature = int((float('result')))
temperature = ['result']

# Write the "Hello World!" string in the buffer and
#   set a more eye-friendly default brightness
scrollphathd.write_string(" Hello World! %.1fC "%(temperature), brightness=0.5)

# Auto scroll using a while + time mechanism (no thread)
while True:
    # Show the buffer
    scrollphathd.show()
    # Scroll the buffer content
    scrollphathd.scroll()
    # Wait for 0.1s
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Error reads: "TypeError: float argument required, not list"
Thank you.

---

OK, I have this working well. Pi2 is reading three parameters from the database on Pi1, and working with them in some `if/elif` to display them on the Scroll PhatHD appropriately.

I'm just wondering. Is there a way in Python to keep the database connection information in a separate file, like I can in PHP, with `require`?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi I can see you are new here, for people to be able to help you, you should post the entire error Stack Trace so that we can see why it is being thrown.

Comment: Noted for next time, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The line

`temperature = ['result']`

sets the `temperature` variable to be a list, while the line

`scrollphathd.write_string(" Hello World! %.1fC "%(temperature), brightness=0.5)`

expects the `temperature` variable to be a `float` type variable.

Replacing that line with `temperature = result[0]` would solve it, but do notice that it doesn't handle the case the query returns an empty response.

Comment: That's fixed it, thank you. I now need to add other fields from the database, which should be straightforward enough I think. I also need  to convert some of them from numeric to text within thresholds. Any pointers would be appreciated but I do enjoy trying things myself and learning from my mistakes.  Thank you.

Comment: @Richard [this](https://pyformat.info/) is a great ressource on formatting any type of data to strings in Python

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error is being caused by this:

```
scrollphathd.write_string(" Hello World! %.1fC "%(temperature), brightness=0.5)
```

you are trying to format the string with `temperature` as a `float` but just above you wrote `temperature = ['result']` which is a list.